# 2 column flexible layout

Tags: jquery, css, css-float

I have 2 column structure. The CSS used are as follows:

```
.div-left
{
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 18%;
margin: 1;
}

.div-right
{
position: relative;
float: right;
width: 81%;
margin: 0;
}
```

I want a flexible structure in the sense, when one column is collapsed other should automatically take up space.

I am trying to hide first column as shown below:

```
$("#test").animate({width: 'toggle'});
```

This is hiding my First column, but the right column is not taking the space released by first column.

I took the javascript to toggle from here (http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions).

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried animating width property of `81%` wide element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution: use CSS transitions (I'm mentioning it because you list CSS3 in your tags) and `.expanded`/ `.collapsed` classes. Then use jQuery just to toggle the classes.

[**demo**](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/ixbyd) (click on a column to make it expand/ come back to initial width)

HTML:

```
<div class='left'></div>
<div class='right'></div>
```

CSS:

```
* { margin: 0; }
div { min-height: 10em; transition: linear 1s; }
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 18%;
  background: crimson;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  width: 81%;
  background: dodgerblue;
}
.expanded { width: 100%; }
.collapsed { width: 0%; }
```

jQuery:

```
$('div').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('expanded').siblings().toggleClass('collapsed');
});
```