# Collapse two columns that meet in the middle

Tags: responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion

The idea is to have two columns at 50%, each with a directional collapse via buttons.

For instance, a real estate site where one half is rows of houses, the other half is a map. The user could choose to look at a full width map or full width listings or both. They could never choose both to be hidden. Only one or the other or both visible.

There are a bunch of things I've seen on here that sort of get at that but maybe I'm searching the wrong terms to find what I'm looking for.

Found this fiddle but it's not quite what I was looking for:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/274NN/5/

Also this page is close but again not where I was going with it:
[Jquery accordion but goes full width](http://jc-designs.net/blog/2011/07/how-to-build-a-horizontal-jquery-accordion/)

Third example is Zillow dot com with buttons in upper corner but I'd want map one to show just map, listing one to show just listing and clicking either again would bring back both (not a 10 rep so I get only two links).

Comment: The jsfiddle seems to do what you're asking. What functionality do you need on top of that?

Comment: Actually, it's not what I was looking for. There would be two buttons above the sliding columns with both at 50% at the page width on load. Click the left button and it shifts the left off making the right 100%. Click again and it is centered back at 50%. Etc...

Comment: Here is another fiddle result:
http://jsfiddle.net/fauzi/q9GLR/show/light/

But rather than being only one column, it should be 50-50 two columns with the ability to reveal all of one or all of the other or both as default at 50%.

Comment: I think you might have better luck without utilizing bootstrap, and just using jquery. Otherwise you're just gonna be hacking at it anyways (ex: col-xs-0 isn't a class).

Comment: Seems you are right. I found this but it is causing problems with the rest of my layout because the code assigns to function to generic div tag. I am now trying to figure out how to make it specific to just those two divs rather than every div on the page.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478597/2-column-flexible-layout